# Get next value in ordered tree

Tags: rust, b-tree

Given an ordered map (like BTreeMap) and a value in the map, how do you get the "next" larger (or smaller) value in the map?

There are many ordered tree libraries. It would be amazing to get an answer for:

1. `BTreeMap`
2. `rudy::rudymap::RudyMap` (https://docs.rs/rudy/latest/rudy/)
3. `art_tree` (https://docs.rs/art-tree/latest/art_tree/)
4. `judy` arrays

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: The attempt is looking in the documentation, and I saw no good looking function in the documentation. However, it's an ordered tree, so it should be O(1) to get "next largest key". I'd be very surprised if rust doesn't supply this functionality. I just can't find it.

Comment: If your questions is "Do these types provide an existing O(1) API to get the next/prev entry, or is there a way to achieve it in O(1) given other parts of their APIs?", the answer is likely "no".

Comment: There may be a way to `O(1)` get the next/prev entry using [`BTreeMap::split_off`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#method.split_off), but I'm not certain, and that would require `&mut` access.

Comment: Do you mean *"if you have a KEY in the map, how to get the next larger/smaller KEY (and associated value)"*? Ordered maps are ordered by key, not by value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the next smaller or larger *key* of a `BTreeMap` by using an iterator from `.range(..)`:

```
use std::ops::Bound;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let map: BTreeMap<&str, i32> = [
        ("a", 1),
        ("c", 4),
        ("h", 0),
        ("m", 2),
        ("z", 5),
    ].into_iter().collect();
    
    let mut iter = map.range(.."h");
    let next_smaller = iter.next_back();
    
    let mut iter = map.range::<&str, _>((Bound::Excluded("h"), Bound::Unbounded));
    let next_larger = iter.next();
    
    println!("next_smaller: {:?}", next_smaller);
    println!("next_larger : {:?}", next_larger);
}
```

```
next_smaller: Some(("c", 4))
next_larger : Some(("m", 2))
```

Getting the next larger looks a bit gnarly since there is no `"h"..` range syntax that excludes `"h"`. You can of course use `"h"..` if you want to, but you'd have to call `.next()` an additional time to skip over the known element.

Comment: Suppose there are a large number of elements in the btree. What is the time complexity of this? (Is it O(1)?)

Comment: @Test it is O(log n)

Comment: I see—is object lookup also O(log n)? That is, is this no worse than finding out whether the original key—"h" in your example—is in the btree?

Comment: @Test yes, key lookup is O(log n) for tree-based structures